# How can I combine two Pick expressions into one?

Tags: function-construction

I want to speed up my code, i.e., replace `Select` by `Pick`.  I think using two `Pick` expressions isn't pretty, but I have no good idea on how to combine them.

```
Select[Permutations@ Range@9,  
  #1 < #4 < #7 && #1/(10 #2 + #3) + #4/(10 #5 + #6) + #7/(10 #8 + #9) == 1 & @@ # &]

Pick[#, #1/(10 #2 + #3) + #4/(10 #5 + #6) + #7/(10 #8 + #9) & @@ Transpose @ #, 1] & @
  Pick[#, Thread[#1 < #4 < #7] & @@ Transpose@#] & @ Permutations @ Range @ 9
```

Comment: "I think two `Pick` isn't pretty..." - sure, but at least the second `Pick[]` has less to choose from, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to speed things up is to use internally fast functions ("vectorized" ones).

Another consideration is that machine-size integer arithmetic is faster than exact rational arithmetic.  If we clear denominators in the second criteria it turns out to be faster.

```
pickCriteria = Compile[{{perms, _Integer, 2}},
  #[[1]] #[[5]] #[[6]] + #[[2]] #[[4]] #[[6]] + #[[3]] #[[4]] #[[5]] - #[[4]] #[[5]] #[[6]] &[
     {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   (* equals part 1 *)
      {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   (* equals part 4 *)
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},   (* equals part 7 *)
      {0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  (* equals 10 * part 2 + part 3 *)
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0},  (* equals 10 * part 5 + part 6 *)
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1}   (* equals 10 * part 8 + part 9 *)
     } . Transpose @ perms]
  ];
Pick[#, Thread[#[[1]] < #[[4]] < #[[7]]] &@ Transpose@#] &@
    Pick[#, pickCriteria[#], 0] &@ Permutations @ Range @ 9 // Timing
  (* {0.134507, {{5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2}}} *)
```

The OP's two versions take `1.795493` and `0.873528` seconds respectively.

Real arithmetic is also fast, but approximate.  A little bit slower than the above.

```
pickCriteriaReal = Compile[{{perms, _Real, 2}},
   Sign @ Chop[#[[1]]/#[[4]] + #[[2]]/#[[5]] + #[[3]]/#[[6]] - 1.] &[
        {{1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`},
         {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`},
         {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`},
         {0.`, 10.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`},
         {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 10.`, 1.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`},
         {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 10.`, 1.`}
      } . Transpose @ perms]
  ];
Pick[#, Thread[#[[1]] < #[[4]] < #[[7]]] &@ Transpose @ #] &@
     Pick[#, pickCriteriaReal[#], 0] &@ Permutations @ N @ Range @ 9 // 
  Round // Timing
  (* {0.205289, {{5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Machine-size integer indeed fast, this also take 0.2 seconds: `Pick[#, #1 (10 #5 + #6) (10 #8 + #9) + 10 #2 ((10 #5 + #6) (#7 - 10 #8 - #9) + #4 (10 #8 + #9)) + #3 ((10 #5 + #6) (#7 - 10 #8 - #9) + #4 (10 #8 + #9)) & @@ Transpose@#, 0] &@Permutations@Range@9 // Timing`

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[#, Sign[(#1 - #4)] + Sign[(#4 - #7)] +
  #1/(10.0 #2 + #3) + #4/(10.0 #5 + #6) +#7/(10.0 #8 + #9) & @@ 
    Transpose@#, 1. - 2] &@ Permutations@Range@9 // Timing

(*{1.138807, {{5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2}}}*)
```

More faster version (Thanks @Michael E2):

```
Pick[#, Function[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i},
  Evaluate[ Sign[a - d] + Sign[d - g] + 
    Simplify[a/(10 b + c) + d/(10 e + f) + g/(10 h + i) - 1 // Together // Numerator]]
  ] @@ Transpose@#, -2] &@Permutations@Range@9 // Timing

  (*{0.218401, {{5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2}}}*)
```

Or

```
Pick[#, Function[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i},
        Evaluate@Simplify[a/(10 b + c) + d/(10 e + f) + g/(10 h + i) - 1 // Together //
            Numerator]] @@ Transpose@#, 0] &@
    Pick[#, Sign[(#1 - #4)] + Sign[(#4 - #7)] & @@ Transpose@#, -2] &@
  Permutations@Range@9 // Timing

(*{0.109201, {{5, 3, 4, 7, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2}}}*)
```

Comment: Yours takes 0.067 sec. on my machine -- much faster than mine.  The use of `Sign[#1-#4]` etc. in place of `Less` saves a lot of time, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Replaced by one equivalent `Pick`, but the net result is a slowdown ...

```
Pick[#, #1 < #4 < #7 && #1/(10 #2 + #3) + #4/(10 #5 + #6) + #7/(10 #8 + #9) == 1 & @@@ #] &@
                                                                         Permutations@Range@9
```